# facebook show all the pics posted in a post in grid format

Tags: facebook, image

Consider the facebook page called 'https://www.facebook.com/1mpics'

So I have got the feed url 'https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=237513286345629&format=rss20'

In the rss, i see all the posts that are posted in this page.

For example consider the post 'https://www.facebook.com/1mpics/posts/772385399525079'. Title "Beautiful and Powerful Ocean"

Open the RSS url (https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=237513286345629&format=rss20) in firefox. It will show you the posts in this page. For the post (https://www.facebook.com/1mpics/posts/772385399525079) it will shows all the thumbnails of the images in the post. (total nine images.)

So when i open the post (https://www.facebook.com/1mpics/posts/772385399525079) in the firefox browser, the actual facebook only shows 4 pics. If i click on the pic it opens a popup. Then i keep doing next, i can see all the 9 images.

SO i there any way that i can see all the 9 images in grid fromat in the facebook for this post (https://www.facebook.com/1mpics/posts/772385399525079).

Comment: No, that is not possible. Facebook decides how many picture they show to the user. (Imagine if it wasn’t just about a dozen photos as with your post, but let’s say a hundred – most users would not want their newsfeed cluttered with a post that shows all of those 100 photos at once.)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense that its waste to show in the post. Is there any way that the all the photos in this post can be viewed in one place in a grid style. Just like the album photos are shown.

Comment: I don’t know of any way to make that happen.